# Replace data with filtered subset of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe fp such as

```
Item Date Quantity
I1   Jun  1202
I1   Jul  1290
I1   Aug  1829
I1   Sep  1710
I2   Jun  892
I2   Jul  910
I2   Aug  791
```

And I have the itemwise subsets of this set on which i need to do some updates like fpItem

```
Item Date Quantity
I1   Jun  1202
I1   Jul  1300
I1   Aug  1900
```

I want to replace the rows in the updated subset (fpItem) to the original dataframe fp such as

```
Item Date Quantity
I1   Jun  1202
I1   Jul  1300
I1   Aug  1900
I2   Jun  892
I2   Jul  910
I2   Aug  791
```

Any suggestions for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(df_subset, by = c("Item", "Date")) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(Quantity.y) & any(!is.na(Quantity.y)))) %>%
  mutate(Quantity = coalesce(Quantity.y, Quantity.x)) %>%
  select(-matches("\\.x|\\.y"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Item [2]
  Item  Date  Quantity
  <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 I1    Jun       1202
2 I1    Jul       1300
3 I1    Aug       1900
4 I2    Jun        892
5 I2    Jul        910
6 I2    Aug        791
```

Comment: Please check the expected output. rbind repeats the rows, whereras I specifically want to remove the rows which are not in the subset (Sep for I1 in this case)

Comment: See my edit, I guess the logic is that if figure has been replaced for an item, we need to remove the item where nothing has been replaced, otherwise we keep all items. Or you will need to elaborate more on that.